# Visual Studio 2013 debug dll in external executable, make changes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll

I'm trying to debug a Vst audio plugin, which is a dll, inside a host.
I managed to open the host.exe from Visual Studio 2013 and the debug works, however to test correctly i need to make some changes in the User Interface of the host.exe but it's not editable.
The debugger takes over as soon as i load the vst inside the host.

Is there anyway to pause the debugger to make some changes in the gui of the host?
Or is there a way to delay the debugger from taking over immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as there is no function with a breakpoint hit, it is still possible to make changes in the host.exe. 
To test specific functions only set breakpoints there and then it is possible to indirictly trigger them via the host.exe whilst doing the changes you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can attach to the VST process and then put a breakpoint in your DLL, before the point where you need to have data changed in the host process. When your breakpoint is hit, you can attempt to modify the memory location where the data sits that you need to modify for your call but you'll need pretty accurate knowledge of how the host process has its data laid out in memory.

You can't bundle VS2013 with your DLL for every user to do the same so this is only useful for testing locally - I wouldn't advise doing this since your changes may have a detrimental effect on the host process (it may have other state that relies on the original data - if you make changes in memory, other parts of the host process may start breaking).

Comment: Isn't there a way to just make some changes in the Gui of the Host.exe with out changing the memory?

Comment: @amaik Your question didn't mention that bit. Not really - once the debugger takes over, the process is stopped. You need to make the UI change before breaking.

Comment: @amaik You can try subclassing some of the controls on the host UI and then calling your code from the message handler but that's going to be a fairly brittle setup. It's easier to debug it, though, since you can detect when something happens to the subclassed controls and respond to those changes.